# How can I discover current endpoints of my c# application programmatically?

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint

How can I code a c# sample for reading my Client endpoint configurations:

```xml
<client>
   <endpoint address="http://mycoolserver/FinancialService.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IFinancialService"
      contract="IFinancialService" name="WSHttpBinding_IFinancialService">
      <identity>
         <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
   </endpoint>
   <endpoint address="http://mycoolserver/HumanResourcesService.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IHumanResourceService"
      contract="IHumanResourceService" name="WSHttpBinding_IHumanResourceService">
      <identity>
         <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
   </endpoint>
```

And the goal is to obtain an array of endpoints address:

```
List<string> addresses = GetMyCurrentEndpoints();
```

As result we would have:

```
[0] http://mycoolserver/FinancialService.svc  
[1] http://mycoolserver/HumanResourcesService.svc
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
// Automagically find all client endpoints defined in app.config
ClientSection clientSection = 
    ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;

ChannelEndpointElementCollection endpointCollection =
    clientSection.ElementInformation.Properties[string.Empty].Value as ChannelEndpointElementCollection;
List<string> endpointNames = new List<string>();
foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endpointElement in endpointCollection)
{
    endpointNames.Add(endpointElement.Name);
}
// use endpointNames somehow ...
```

(Taken from http://mostlytech.blogspot.com/2007/11/programmatically-enumerate-wcf.html)

Answer (score 18):

This is my first answer ever.  Be gentle :)

```
private List<string> GetMyCurrentEndpoints()
{
    var endpointList = new List<string>();

    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var serviceModel = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);

    foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endpoint in serviceModel.Client.Endpoints)
    {
        endpointList.Add(endpoint.Address.ToString());
    }

    return endpointList;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Just for anyone who is trying to use this on web application, you should have an ArgumentException like ´exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe.´ For reading the client section, @Dmitry tip is fine. But I am also voting up your answer!