# Getting current endpoint behaviors

Tags: c#, wcf

How do I get the endpoint behaviors for the current endpoint being called in a WCF service?

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="Tracking">
    <reporting />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Comment: This should help;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102179/how-can-i-discover-current-endpoints-of-my-c-sharp-application-programmatically

Comment: So, I could look at all of the endpoints and compare the endpoint BindingName to the service BindingNamespace : Binding (with some string manipulation to make it match), but that will fail if there are multiple endpoints that use the same binding.